# Shell Script to delete several lines of text in build.prop

Tags: shell, sed

I have this script in `build.prop` :

```
Battery Saver<br>
wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=180<br>
pm.sleep_mode=1<br>
ro.ril.disable.power.collapse=0
```

And now I want to delete it but can I delete all of the lines from `Battery Saver` to `ro.ril.disable.power.collapse=0` ?

What script may I need to delete all of the lines? can I use `sed` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use sed.

```
sed '/^Battery Saver/,/^ro\.ril\.disable\.power\.collapse=0/d' file
```

Add end of the line anchor if necessary,

```
sed '/^Battery Saver$/,/^ro\.ril\.disable\.power\.collapse=0$/d' file
```

Comment: that script for linux or android?
i need the script for android

how about sed -i 'battery saver,ro.ril.disable.power.collapse=0' /system/build.prop ?

Comment: this sed would for any.. Add `-i` to save the changes made `sed -i '/^Battery Saver/,/^ro\.ril\.disable\.power\.collapse=0/d' file`